# How to proprerly bind text to a SQLite prepared statement with sqlite_bind_text

Tags: sql, sqlite

If the following SQL using the `sqlite3_prepare_v2` is run, it generates the expected results.

```
select id, path, name
from media
where id in (
    select media_id
    from media_tags
    where tag_id in (
       select id 
       from tags
       where name in ( 'name_1', 'name_2', 'name_5', 'name_8', 'name_43' ) )
    group by media_id
    having count( media_id ) = 5 );
```

But if it is changed to

```
select id, path, name
from media
where id in (
    select media_id
    from media_tags
    where tag_id in (
       select id 
       from tags
       where name in ( ? ) )
    group by media_id
    having count( media_id ) = ? );
```

and `sqlite3_bind_text( stmt, 1, char_ptr, -1, SQLITE_STATIC )`
and `sqlite3_bind_int( stmt, 2, 5 )` are employed, no results are returned and there are no errors.

If the `in` clause names are hard coded and only the media_id count of 5 is set with `sqlite3_bind_int`, then the expected results are returned.

Hard coding the 5 and attempting to bind the names with `sqlite3_bind_text` does not return results.

In all cases, the statement is prepared successfully, at least an error code is not generated at that step.

If char_ptr is printed to the screen, it is `'name_1', 'name_2', 'name_5', 'name_8', 'name_43'`.

I must be misunderstanding something simple. Would you tell what I'm missing?

Thank you.

---

I posted this question on the SQLite forum also and received a response concerning what may be a relatively new feature that will allow for one `?` in the `in` set, which appears to indicate that the prepared statement can be prepared at compile time even for a variable number of elements in the set. It's called the `carray array extension function`. I haven't tried it yet but figured I'd better [link](https://sqlite.org/forum/forumpost/fb74d21679) it now in case I forget later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use a ? per bind variable as in:

```
where name in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

and then call sqlite3_bind_text for each.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't thought of that at all, thanks. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Sometimes you generate both the sql query itself and the matching bind statements at run-time.

Comment: Thank you. That appears to work. The number and names of desired tags will vary; so, there appears to be no advantage to storing a prepared statement because it'll have to be prepared anew at each request. May as well just include the names and number in the SQL query text itself rather than use question marks and bind statements.

Comment: A response to a post on the SQLite forum described the `Carray` method that can accept a single `?` in the `in`. I added to the end of my original question. I didn't get to try it yet but think it requires the newest version of SQLite from this month 3.34.